# I have a problem creating a slug for the link. I want to show the numbers in the link

Tags: php

I have this code and it works without problems, but the numbers cannot be shown in the link. Can you help? Thank you

```
$title = ' domin name انا هنا & _ : 09.12.2022';
function slug($string) {
        $regex = "/\.$/";          
        $regex = "/\.+$/";       
        $regex = "/[.*?:'!@#$&-_ ]+$/";
        $result = preg_replace($regex, "", $string);
        $val= preg_replace('/\s+/u', '-', trim($result));
        return strtolower($val); 
    }   
    $slugs = slug($title);
echo $slugs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you might like to try

```
<?php

$title = ' domin name انا هنا & _ : 09.12.2022';

function slug($string) {
    $regex = "/\.$/";          
    $regex = "/\.+$/";       
    // $regex = "/[.*?!@#$&-_ ]+$/";
    $result = preg_replace($regex, "", $string);
    $val= preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', trim($result));
    $val= preg_replace('/[.:_]+/u', '-', trim($val));
    return strtolower($val); 
}
echo slug($title);
```